# Array Implementation of Queue

Tags: java, beginner, array, queue

I've implemented the queue data structures using array in java. Anything I need to change in my code?

**Queue.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Queue<T> {

    private int front;
    private int rear;
    int size;
    T[] queue;

    public Queue(int inSize) {
        size = inSize;
        queue = (T[]) new Object[size];
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }

    public boolean isempty() {
        return (front == -1 && rear == -1);
    }

    public void enQueue(T value) {
        if ((rear+1)%size==front) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is full");

        } else if (isempty()) {
            front++;
            rear++;
            queue[rear] = value;

        } else {
            rear=(rear+1)%size;
            queue[rear] = value;

        }
    }

    public T deQueue() {
        T value = null;
        if (isempty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is empty, cant dequeue");
        } else if (front == rear) {
            value = queue[front];
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;

        } else {
            value = queue[front];
            front=(front+1)%size;

        }
        return value;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Queue [front=" + front + ", rear=" + rear + ", size=" + size
                + ", queue=" + Arrays.toString(queue) + "]";
    }

}
```

**QueueImpl.java**

```
public class QueueImpl {

    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
        Queue newQueue = new Queue(5);
        newQueue.enQueue(10);
        newQueue.enQueue(20);
        newQueue.enQueue(30);
        newQueue.enQueue(40);
        newQueue.enQueue(50);
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.toString());
        newQueue.enQueue(60);
        newQueue.enQueue(70);
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());
        System.out.println((T) newQueue.toString());


    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your fields `size` and `queue` have package access, they need to be private so only your class can control them.

```
private final int size;
private final T[] queue;
```

And because their values are known at initialization, its good practice to declare them `final`.

your `isempty` method is not `Camelcase`, use `isEmpty` instead.
Some validation on the `size` parameter is needed as well.

```
 if(size<=0){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be less than or equal to zero");
 }
```

Something I love about the `this` keyword is that it helps you finding a name for your variables

```
 public Queue(int size) { // size is more relevant than inSize 
   if(size<=0){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be less than or equal to zero");
    }
    this.size = size;
    queue = (T[]) new Object[size];
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought of doing size check, but i forgot while implementing my code :(

Comment: thats very common :(

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a Java guy.*

But....

- This `If` needs some breathing space.

  > ```
  > public void enQueue(T value) {
  >     if ((rear+1)%size==front) {
  > ```

  It would be much more readable like this:

  ```
  if ((rear + 1) % size == front) {
  ```
- Same goes for this statement later in the same `enQueue` method.

  > ```
  > rear=(rear+1)%size;
  > ```
- Actually, it looks like you could extract a function there.
- `deQueue` also suffers from inconsistent (and poor) whitespace.
- I know it's just an example implementation to show us that it works, but `QueueImpl` is a poor name. There's no reason to abbrv names. It's not the 1960's. We're not counting bytes in our names anymore. Prefer clear, concise, and meaningful names over shortened ones.
- Speaking of the example implementation, it would be better to write an actual Unit Test than to print to the console.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to write unit test cases from my next programs.

Answer (score 5):

You have a memory hog when using a large queue.

Because you store the object references and don't null them on retrieval, one could store a object reference to an object that references a great deal of other objects. Once I dequeue this object, it remains in your array and is not garbage collected.

Comment: how to avoid this?

Comment: "Because you store the object references and don't null them on retrieval, (...)": null the object references on retrieval.

Answer (score 3):

The size field is not required (just use queue.length)

In fact, the size field is a misnomer, because it is the *capacity*, not the size.  The size is the number of elements that the queue actually contains, while the capacity is the maximum number of elements that it can hold.

In enQueue, you have a special case for the empty queue, and in deQueue you have a special case for the singleton queue.  These special cases are avoidable.  Instead of representing the empty queue with `head == rear == -1` you could keep a separate size field (to remember how many elements are in the queue).  Or you could use a different invariant:

```
queue empty iff head == rear
queue full  iff rear == (head+1) % queue.length
```